# Getting a value of input after it loads

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to fetch the value of an input and add a class to it but when I run getelementbyClassname it does not work.

I guess this is because when the script runs the input hasn't generated yet. How can I get the value after it loads?

You can see an example here. https://garbanzo-nyc.myshopify.com/products/large-square-box

I want to add a class and fetch the value of each radio button.

> For exmaple since sample-swatch is added in the html it loads in
>   console. When i try to get box-mats the code doesn't run since it's
>   being generated when the page loads. So when the script runs it
>   doesn't find anything initially. But when i type it in the dom it
>   works because the content has loaded.

```
  var sample = document.getElementsByClassName("sample-swatch");
  console.log(sample[0])

  var boxmats = document.getElementsByClassName("box-mats");
  console.log(boxmats[0])
```

Comment: You run the code after it loads, then. I did notice your names on those radio buttons could just be a single name. `if(Element.checked){ /* Element.value is relevant */ }`. Run in a loop if need be.

Comment: "<input type="radio" name="properties[box_mat]" value="Black" class="spb-productoptiontextcolor spb-productoptionbackground">" this is autogenerated by the plugin. I can't change this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt know what getElementByClassName is. Since a class can pertain to multiple elements, you use `getElementsByClassName`, plural. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I was using var xxx = document.getElementsByClassName("sample-swatch");